# Error while building rosjava_core (gradle wrapper)

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am trying to install rosjava_core on fuerte (ubuntu 12.04) using tutorial http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html . I have followed the "Installing rosjava_core" sections. Now I am trying "building rosjava_core" and executing first step given "./gradlew install" . It creates a zip file gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip (which I can see) but then I get error:

```
Unzipping /home/safdar/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip to /home/safdar/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:148)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:148)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:47)
```

Any body who already has had such error? or how can I proceed further now?
thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46466/error-while-building-rosjava_core-(gradle-wrapper)/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-23**:
thanks.Now it proceeds but I get following error on ./gradlew test: Test org.ros.time.NtpTimeProviderTest FAILED
129 tests completed, 1 failure

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':rosjava:test'.  Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the zip download failed, delete the zip file and try again.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-23**:
Hi Kruse! thanks,its installed. Now if I execute ../gradlew installApp it builds successfully but I dont see any bin directory because I dont get Talker running if I execute ./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker  Any clue to run Talker?